# Beautiful Soup + Pandas outputs only the last item in CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

Strange! I am using `Beautiful Soup 4` and `Pandas` with `Python 3.8`. I am trying to **scrape** the data from a webpage using `requests`. My code prints out all the properties on a first page but unable to write them all into a CSV file, instead it writes only the last item. What am I missing here? Code below.

```
listofProperties = []
for property in properties:
    pdFrame = {}
    pdFrame["House Price"] = property.find("a", class_ = "text-price").text.replace("\n", "").replace("Offers over", "").replace(" ", "")
    pdFrame["House Address"] = property.find("a", class_ = "listing-results-address").text
    pdFrame["Number of Beds"] = property.find("span", class_ = "num-beds")['title']
    pdFrame["Number of Baths"] = property.find("span", class_ = "num-baths")['title']
    pdFrame["Number of Reception Rooms"] = property.find("span", class_ = "num-reception")['title']
    pdFrame["Sold By"] = property.find("p", class_ = "listing-results-marketed").find("span").text
    propertyArea = random.randint(300,2200)
    propertyArea = str(propertyArea)
    pdFrame["House Size"] = propertyArea + " sq. ft"
    pdFrame["Agent Phone"] = property.find("span", class_ = "agent_phone").text.replace(" **", "").replace("\n", "")

listofProperties.append(pdFrame)
print(len(listofProperties))
print(listofProperties)
df = pandas.DataFrame(listofProperties)
df.to_csv("scrapedProperties.csv", index=False)
```

Any help appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: pdFrame = {} should be outside the loop. You initialize it to nothing each time and get the last data. Or you could put the append inside the loop.

Comment: move ``listofProperties.append(pdFrame)`` into for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I had a minor mistake in my code, I was calling this `listofProperties.append(pdFrame)` outside the loop. @sushanth pointed this out.

Thank you!